# How to prevent deletion of related ForeignKey instances?

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I have:

- Model1
- Model2 with field ForeignKey(Model1)

I want to delete Model1 instance, but when I do it, the related Model2 instance is deleted too. How to prevent its deletion?

Comment: For a global override, check out the arguments you can pass to ForeignKey fields: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear (set to `None`) the foreign key field of the Model2 instance or point it to some other Model1 instance, before removing the Model1 instance. Otherwise data consistency would be broken if Model1 instance was removed by the Model2 instance not.